# Java/Groovy Binary Tree Insertion

Tags: java, groovy, tree

I am trying to write a binary tree recursive insertion and I not getting anywhere for last hours. I either get a stackoverflow error or not all items are being inserted.

I want to insert these values in my tree:

```
binaryTree.addNodeRecursion(new MNode(50, "fourth"))
binaryTree.addNodeRecursion(new MNode(25, "third"))
binaryTree.addNodeRecursion(new MNode(15, "second"))
binaryTree.addNodeRecursion(new MNode(10, "first"))
binaryTree.addNodeRecursion(new MNode(75, "fifth"))
binaryTree.addNodeRecursion(new MNode(85, "sixth"))
```

I want to do this without passing the root around as a parameter. So my code looks like this:

```
   public void addNodeRecursion(MNode newNode){

        if(root == null) {
            root = newNode
        }else{
            addRecurs(newNode); //this is the recursive function, it should not return a node object
        }
    }
```

Note, that I am not talking about a Binary Search Tree but a Binary tree, where elements order is not relevant. I care about how elements are inserted. I want to insert them as it is show below:

```
1 Step: 
            50

2 Step:
            50
           /
          25

3 Step:
            50
           /  \
          25  15

4 Step:
            50
           /  \
          25  15
         /
        10

5 Step:
            50
           /  \
          25  15
         /  \
        10  75

6 Step: (now notice that I am going back to the sibling of the current parent)

             50
           /   \
          25    15
         /  \   /
        10  75 85
```

Now here is my `addRecurs` function:

```
private void addRecurs(MNode newNode) {

    if(newNode == null) { return };

    if(root.leftNode == null){ //Step 2 if the left node is null assign it
        root.leftNode = newNode 
    }else{ //Else that means the right Node is null
        root.rightNode = newNode // Step 3 set the right node
        root = root.leftNode // the the parent to the left node
        addRecurs(newNode) // repeat
    }

};
```

It doesn't work.

Can this be done without tracking or storing the parent in a variable?

Comment: DO you have a simple complete example that shows your problem?

Comment: No, this is just something I am trying to do in my free time. I came up with the problem myself and trying to solve it. The main issue is that I want to insert elements in a specific order as I showed with the steps

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you back your tree by a something like a [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). Basically a tree structure based on an array, you seem not to need the sorting part, so it is very simple. For a better answer we would need more information

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777011/java-binary-tree-recursion-methods).

```
static void addNode(node n)
{
    if(root==null)
    {
        root = n;
    }
    else
    {
        node tmp = root; // save the current root
        if(root.getValue()>n.getValue())
        {
            root = root.leftLink;
            addNode(n);
        }
        else if(root.getValue()<n.getValue())
        {
            root = root.rightLink;
            addNode(n);
        }
        root = tmp; // put the root back to its original value
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is the thing. The guy here uses comparison. I just enter my values without comparing. Removing the if in that code will not work.